# Export buttons are not shown for my datatable on my page - JS Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, asp.net-4.5

I have a datatable in javascript. The loaded JS libraries are listed below, exactly in that order.

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

The datatable is created like below:

```
myTable = $('#example').on('error.dt', function (e, settings, techNote, message) {
                                console.log('An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message);
                            }).DataTable({
                                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                                buttons: ['copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
                                ],
                                fixedColumns: true,
                                "columnDefs": [{
                                    //"bSortable": false,
                                    "width": '60%',
                                    "defaultContent": "-",
                                    "targets": "_all"
                                }]
                            });
```

The problem is, I do not see the export button on the browser. I am using Google Chrome. In the similar questions, people say that the order of the JS libraries matter, but my order is matching with theirs. In Site Settings, Flash is also allowed. There is no error in the console of the Chrome when I press F12. I could not find why the buttons are not shown on the screen. Tried not using Html5 while setting the buttons, did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have already done this, but just to check...have you also loaded the CSS for the buttons?

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This example based on your code is working for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DataTables With Export</title>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<h1>DataTables</h1>
<table class="table display" id="example" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script> 
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
myTable = $('#example').on('error.dt', function (e, settings, techNote, message) {
    console.log('An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message);
}).DataTable({
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: ['copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'],
    fixedColumns: true,
    "columnDefs": [{
    //"bSortable": false,
    "width": '60%',
    "defaultContent": "-",
    "targets": "_all"
    }]
});
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```